# Best way for apache HttpClients using in a multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-httpcomponents

I need to create a service on the server-side for sending HTTP requests. It works like this:

```
1. Client sends a request to the server
2. Server uses singleton service for calling 3rd-party API via HTTP.
3. API returns the response
4. Server process this response and return it to the client
```

It is a synchronized process.

I created service:

```
public class ApacheHttpClient {

    private final static CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

    public String sendPost(String serverUrl, String body) {
        try {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverUrl);
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(body));
           
            CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

            String responseAsString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            response.close();

            return responseAsString;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RestException(e);
        }
    }
```

`ApacheHttpClient` is a singleton in my system. `CloseableHttpClient client` is a singleton too.

Question 1: Is it correct to use one instance of `CloseableHttpClient client` or I should create a new instance for each request?
Question 2: When I should close the client?
Question 3: This client can process only 2 connections in one time period. Should I use an executor?

Comment: You can take a look at [performance](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/performance.html)

Comment: I would really avoid converting HTTP response to a string. This looks wasteful and inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The use of HttpClient instance as a singleton per distinct HTTP service is correct and is in line with the Apache HttpClient best practices. It should *not* be static, though.

   http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.1.x/migration-guide/preparation.html
2. One should close HttpClient when releasing the HTTP service. In your case `ApacheHttpClient` should implement `Closeable` and close the internal instance of `CloseableHttpClient` in its `#close` method.
3. You probably should not, but it really depends on how exactly your application deals with request execution.

Comment: Can you clarify point 2? What do you mean under this phrase "One should close HttpClient when releasing the HTTP service"? I do it like this: the application starts and creates a singleton with internal `ApacheHttpClient `.  The application can work a long time while it is necessary. When somebody or something tries down this application "shutdown" method is called and the application closes all resources like `ApacheHttpClient `. Is it the correct understanding?

Comment: It is. Essentially, in your particular case the life span of ApacheHttpClient equals that of the entire application.

Comment: Thank you, I will accept your answer. But, I noticed strange behavior in this implementation - sometimes I get an exception: `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset`. A repeated request is successful. It looks like `ApacheHttpClient ` loses socket connection if it works as singleton during a long time without requests and repair connection after failed request.

Comment: It is not a strange behavior. It is pretty normal. HTTP endpoints can terminate the connection at any point of time, especially if idle for too long. However one can evict expired / idle connections proactively to minimize request retries due to a stale connection.

Comment: the link is broken, up-to-date one is https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.3.x/migration-guide/preparation.html